# html5 websockets on sharedhosting blocking other ports

Tags: php, linux, html

I can't use websockets at the moment because I am on shared hosting and it doesn't allow binding to any of the other ports. Is there a way to go through port 80 somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a websocket module for apache available. This might help if you need both the webserver and the websocket on port 80. But if you on shared hosting it is not likely that it is installed.

So there will be no way on shared hosting. Sorry.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm on a shared hosting too. Having the same issue. But if I where a shared hoster I wouldn't allow for websockets too as this could lead to situations where the maximum connections limit is reached quickly.

Comment: just have to wait for the popular web servers to adopt this then :). I am looking for a way to update the client and post data to the server many times per minute whilst reducing server requests, any ideas?

Comment: No ideas without sockets. Js api's usually used polling before HTML5 sockets came up and if sockets aren't available. Note that having a connection open over a large time together with a reasonable number of users will *take down* the server earlier than polling requests every 10 seconds because of the number of open connections. Also a socket server is a state machine what is much more complicated to maintain than a stateless web server. But however, I know sockets are interesting. As a former flash developer I could use them 10 years ago ;)